# Insert javascript variables into databasw

Tags: javascript, php, database

I have this function in javascript

```
function addRow( i , name , first , second , final , partic , abc , Grade){
    names[i] = name;
    fiM[i] = first;
    secM[i] = second;
    finalM[i] = final;
    parti[i] = partic;
    Y_N[i] = ABC;
    grades[i] = Grade;
}
```

I want to insert the parameters of this function into a database using php
I tried to solve this problem using ajax but I think I didn't used it correctly

I tried this code:

```
function addRow( i , name , first , second , final , partic , abc , Grade){
        
    computeBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open(
        "GET",
        "addStudent.php?first=" +
          first+
          "&second=" +
          second +
          "&final=" +
          final +
          "&prt=" +
          partic+
          "&abc = " +
          abc +
          "&name = " +
          name+
          "&grade = " +grade
          ,
        true
      );
      xmlhttp.send();
      xmlhttp.onstatechange = function () {
        console.log(xmlhttp.response);
      };
    });
        
    names[i] = name ;
    fiM[i] = first ;
    secM[i] = second ;
    finalM[i] = final ;
    parti[i] = partic ;
    Y_N[i] = abc ;
    grades[i] = Grade ;
         
}
```

and in php file

```
<?php      
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","12345678", "advanceweb");

$name = $_GET['name'];
$first = $_GET['first'];
$second = $_GET['second'];
$final = $_GET['final'];
$prt = $_GET['prt'];
$abs = $_GET['abc'];
$g = $_GET['grade'];

$q_insert = "INSERT INTO `newstudent` (`StudentName`, `first`, `second`, `final`, `partcipation`, `Absences`, `grade`) VALUES ('$name','$first','$second','$final','$prt','$abs','$g')";
mysqli_query($con, $q_insert);

mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Can anyone help me to correct it please?

Comment: Your sql is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I don't really see what that initial function `addRow` really does other than modify values in some global variables. and the next portion of javascript has a different version of this with ajax.  Can you clarify what the purpose is and perhaps explain how it is used and where these variables come from?

Comment: Well, what error are you getting? What debugging have you done? Are you actually calling the addRow() function from anywhere? I don't see it.

Comment: Without knowing a specific issue to fix, there are several things in the code which are poor practice and suggest you haven't had proper teaching in how to do some key tasks: I really recommend using POST to send lots of data like this, I recommend URL-encoding anything you _do_ put on the querystring, and I strongly recommend protecting your database from both SQL injection attacks _and_ basic syntax errors (e.g. just a simple `'` in one of the input fields would break your query currently) by using prepared statements and parameters, instead of sending raw queries direct to the database.

Comment: You also have a few inconsistencies with the case used for variables. In Javascript case is important so `abc!=ABC` etc